# Testing Xamarin Navigation methods with context Binding on destination page fails

Tags: xaml, testing, xamarin, mocking

I have a problem with Xamarin framework. I am trying to test a Navigation.PushAsync method and I get an error:

"You must call Xamarin.Forms Init() prior using it"

**Scenario**

Just imagine a simple content page in Xamarin which looks like this in the code behind.

```
public partial class TesterPage : ContentPage
{


    public TesterPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML part for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 

         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BoatInspectorPMS.TesterPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is out destination page. We have the origin page that looks like this partly.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
     private readonly IPageService _pageService;

     public MainViewModel(IPageService pageService)
     {
        _pageService = pageService;
     }

     public async Task NewSurvey()
     {
        await _pageService.PushAsync(new TesterPage());
     }
}
```

The interface IPageService looks like this:

```
public interface IPageService
{
    Task PushAsync(Page page);
}
```

So we want to run a test which looks like this. Here is our test.

```
    [Test]
    public async Task OurTest()
    {           
        //mock PageService
        var pageService = new Mock<PageService>();
        var mvm = new MainViewModel(pageService.Object);

        await mvm.NewSurvey();
        pageService.Verify(p => p.PushAsync(It.IsAny<TesterPage>()));

    }
```

I get an error in the constructor of TesterPage at InitializeComponent() at the moment when it enters auto generated code

```
  private void InitializeComponent() {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(TesterPage));
    }
```

Pretty stuck on this issue. Hope someone has come across a similar situation. Thank you.

Comment: are you calling this before the MainActivity.cs in your android project hits the xamarin init method?

Comment: I am not calling mainactivity at all, this code is executed in the pcl project.

Comment: ok search the project for the xamarin init method and put a breakpoint there, i assume its in the mainactivity.cs, not sure if it exists at all

Comment: The init method is in the app.cs class in the pcl project and it is not called during tests so putting a break point there wont take us anywhere.

Comment: i completely missed the test point. im sorry

Comment: @YuriZolotarev: Did you a solution for this. I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I need a solution also..